# MySQL string option with unlimited character count?

Tags: mysql

I need to store huge amounts of text in a column of my MySQL database, but all of the types I've used so far are not big enough E.G. text, LongBlob, Longtext.

How can I store large amounts of characters in a column in a MySQL database, what type of column must I use?

Comment: Is it an option to store the huge text in a separate file and just put the filename in the database?

Comment: I needed it for things like help articles. And yes!, I never thought of that, thankyou Kerrek.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't shoehorn it into longtext, you can't do it.
That being said, I cannot imagine you'd really want to do that.  What sort of table is going to have multiple rows of 2GB chunks of text, and will be able to functionally use that for anything?